# htaccess starts with optional parameters

Tags: .htaccess

i need to have an optional starting parameter at htaccess

Urls that i need to trigger

```
/offers
/category1/offers
/category1/category2/offers
```

i have implement this scenario in multi-language sites as follow

```
RewriteRule ^(en|de)/?(.*)/offers/?$ offers.php?lang=$1&url=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

The rule above trigger the following urls

```
/en/offers
/en/category1/offers
/en/category1/category2/offers
/de/offers
/de/category1/offers
/de/category1/category2/offers
```

etc

and its working perfectly

Now i have a single language site and the language parameters does not exist and i have implement the same scenario

So fo trigger

```
/offers
/category1/offers  
/category1/category2/offers
```

i have implement the following rule that is not working

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/offers/?$ offers.php?url=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

and i guess its has to do with the starts with in the rule but i dont know  how to solve it

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep 2 rules separate non-conflicting then use:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|de)/(.+)/offers/?$ offers.php?lang=$1&url=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(?:(.+)/)?offers/?$ offers.php?url=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when the first parameter is missing the rule is not working ex /offers is not working while /category1/offers is working.Keep in mind that i want the rule without any language

Comment: /offers and 
/category1/offers and
/category1/category2/offers
thats the urls

Comment: Please edit question with more clarity. For each example URI what should be rewritten URI. e.g. `/offers` is not covered by any of your shown rules.

Comment: Thats exactly my problem that /offers in not trigger

Comment: Please provide answer to my questions by editing your question. I can easily provide a solution but need to know clear set of requirements.

Comment: You have a rule that starts with `^(en|de)/` but none of your example URLs match `/en/` or `/de/` so clearly examples don't match all requirements.

Comment: I have made some edits and try to be more clear.Can you tell me if now its more understandalbe.

Comment: In the rule languages are not required and you dont need to add the in the rule

Comment: `(?!(?:en|de)/)` is negative lookahead. This will only match if language is not present at start.

Comment: /offers is not triggering

Comment: RewriteRule ^offers/?$ offers.php [L,NC]  i know that i can do that but i am trying to avoid because i will and more optional parameters i will have double rules.

Comment: Sorry to say this but if you had spent time upfront in writing clear requirements, you would have got a working answer in first attempt. Even after so many comments and edits, question still doesn't mention expected rewritten URI for each example URI.

Comment: RewriteRule ^?(.*)/offers  is cause http500
RewriteRule ^(.*)?/offers  not trigger /offers

Comment: Have reduced to 2 rules again in answer.